# Rails: Determine whether currently within asset compilation step

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

We have a method where we'd like it to behave one way when it's being invoked during asset compilation, and another way otherwise. Is there a way to determine whether the code is currently within the context of an asset compilation?

Comment: So ultimately, you want your pre-compiled assets file to have something like `foo(){return bar;}` and your individual asset file to have `foo(){return baz;}`. Is that your desired result?